# Need to pay 25 USD to use Google Oauth2 authentication?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api-php-client

I used my google account developer for quite a long time (2-3 months).
I created a Google Oauth2 app, got clientid, access token and all the stuff. Working perfecty. My website's using a PHP client for OAuth2 auth.

Today I'm went to the website and I received the error:

> Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_request: Missing
>   parameter: client_id'

I went to my developer console (thinking the client_id was different for some weird reason) and I found out I can't access the console anymore, Google is asking me a fee of 25 USD to access again.

Is it normal? Why such a misleading error message from the PHP client?

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot above you are registering a developer account to publish apps in the google play store, they take a small fee - yes

Comment: So I went to the wrong login page? Where I should go to manage my current OAuth2 app

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: ok it works. So now why I get such error? the client id is fine